# (Dis)prove that the sequence of nested prime counting function diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

It's a question I think not proposed yet :

Define $\pi(x)$ as the prime counting function then define :

$$S(n)=\pi\left(1\pi\left(2\pi\left(3\pi\left(4\pi\left(5\pi\left(6\pi\left(7\pi\left(...\pi\left(n\right)...\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

First I conjectured that it was less than $n$ wich is false for a small value of $n$ .

As it's seems to define a sequence does it diverges ?

I think yes but I cannot show it : Does someone have an idea (asymptotic behavior)?

Comment: https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/l/l170.htm.

Comment: What happens if you, incorrectly, use the exact $\pi(n) = \frac{n}{\ln n}$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't know but we can use Dusart theorem .